# Why can I use entity manager in controller and not in Command?

Tags: postgresql, symfony, ubuntu, doctrine-orm

I have created a service for getting the entity manager in a command

I don't understand why I can use the entity manager in regular Controller and not in my Command.

I have declared my service in "*service.yml*"

```
common.doctrine:
        class: AppBundle\Services\GetDoctrineService
        arguments: [ '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager' ]
        public: true
```

I wrote it in "*GetDoctrineService.php*"

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Services;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class GetDoctrineService
{
  protected $em;

  public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em)
  {
    $this->em = $em;
  }

  public function getRepository(string $repo) {
      return $this->em->getRepository($repo);
  }
}
```

In my command, I am importing it and calling it in the "Command way"

```
$em = $this->getApplication()->getKernel()->getContainer()->get('common.doctrine');
$foo = $em->getRepository(Entity::FOO)->findAll();
```

I changed the db host to "*localhost*" in "*parameters.yml*"

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    #database_host: db-name
    database_host: localhost
```

When I installed postgres with a command, the file "*pg_hba.conf*" wasn't created (I am working with Ubuntu)

**I have this error while i use my command :**

**Message: "An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused     Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"**

Comment: Why not directly inject the entitymanager in your command by declaring it as a service? https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/console/commands_as_services.html.

Nevertheless it looks like your database is unreachable, does it work in your regular code ?

Comment: My command doesn't need to be sophisticated, it's for only one use. When I use entity manager in the controllers, it works perfectly

Comment: Did you check the error log of postgresql ?

Comment: I don't have postgres logs
The error come when I i am trying to access the repo Entity::FOO

Comment: You should have log files in /var/log/postgresql ? The error message you provided states that there is no service running on on localhost:5432 or that it is no accepting incoming connections. So first you should be sure Postgresql is running correctly.

Comment: In my logs, I only have dev.log and prod.log. I can read and write in the db from the controllers

Comment: I am not talking about  your Symfony logs, but your Postgresql log probably in /var/log on your server. 

Are you sure you are using the same connection settings from your controller ? 
Which Symfony version are you running ? And do you use environment variables for SQL settings ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the configuration files:
using 'localhost' was a mistake: we should have use the dn-name for the host